# How do I find an analytical solution of $x x' + \frac 3 2 (x')^2 + A \frac {x'} x = W$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve the Rayleigh-Plesset equation of a bubble made of super-critical fluid, and its radius varies as a function of time. A generalised form of the equation I got is:

$$x x' + \frac 3 2 (x')^2 + A \frac {x'} x = W .$$

Here $A$ and $W$ are constants. How do I go about solving this system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x x' + \frac 3 2 (x')^2 + A \frac {x'} x = W .$$
We observe that $x(t)$ is an even function. This draw to the change of function :
$$X=x^2 \quad\to\quad dX=2xdx \quad\to\quad x'=\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dX}\frac{dX}{dt}=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{dX}{dt}$$
$$x \left(\frac{1}{2x}\frac{dX}{dt} \right) + \frac 3 2 \left(\frac{1}{2x}\frac{dX}{dt} \right)^2 + \frac {A}{x} \left(\frac{1}{2x}\frac{dX}{dt} \right)= W .$$
$$ 3 \left(\frac{dX}{dt} \right)^2 + 4(X+A)\frac{dX}{dt} - 8WX =0 $$
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=\frac{2}{3}\left(X+A\pm\sqrt{(X+A)^2+6WX } \right)$$ 
$$t=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{dX}{X+A\pm\sqrt{(X+A)^2+6WX } }$$
$$t=t_0+\frac{3}{2}\int_{x_0^2}^{x^2} \frac{dX}{X+A\pm\sqrt{(X+A)^2+6WX } }$$
This will give $t(x)$ on form of an huge formula. It's doubtful that the inverse function $x(t)$ could be expressed on closed form.

Comment: I assumed the constants A and W to be unity and integrated with the limits 0 to Inf, with 0 being symbolising the formation of the bubble and Inf, the brush bubble. I got the integral to be =0.3576, this represented in the equation would be

Comment: t=t(0) + 1.0728. My question is rather than doing this, can't we solve the integral using Weierstrasses Elliptic function? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The integral can be analytically solved. No need for Elliptic integrals, elementary functions are sufficient  :  http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dX%2F%28X%2BA%2Bsqrt%28%28X%2BA%29%5E2%2B6+W+X%29%29+&x=0&y=0 . But, the problem is the inversion for $x(t)$. Numerical calculus is required. Also, there is a problem of no convergence. You will have to verify all steps of the calculus to see if there is no mistake. I will not be available for several days.

Comment: thanks a lot!Yeah I arrived at a similar result after checking via MATLAB.